# Does anyone know how to set the UK date format when using pyephem

Tags: date, pyephem

I am using the almanac functions from pyephem and although my locale is set to United kingdom functions like $almanac.next_equinox always return the date in US format rather than UK

for example I get Equinox: 03/20/14 16:57:06 from $almanac.next_equinox but I want 20/03/2014 16:57:06

The OS is OSX 10.9 Mavericks with 2.7 of python installed.

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Could you provide a complete little code snippet that outputs the date that way for us to take a look at? Thanks!